# How do I append / merge additional XML into an existing XML field in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a column in SQL Server 2005 that stores a simple chunk of XML.  At a later point processing is performed and I need to merge some processing info into the XML.

While I can do this at an intermediate point I would much prefer to keep this method centraliazed within the stored procedure that is responsible for updating other fields post-processing.

[Here's an example](http://paste-it.net/public/d7d8ab3/) of the XML I'm starting with and the type of outcome I'd like to achieve.  Can anyone provide me some rough SQL to achieve it?

**Update:** Finally got it!  I'll post the full solution when I get the chance, it was enough of a hack that someone else will hopefully find it useful

**All finished!** In the end I had a couple of additional requirements that required me to rework Marc's suggested solution and ditch the .modify() function entirely; however his answer let me get past my initial hurdles and got me to where I could step back and spot the easier approach.  [Here's my final solution](http://www.paste-it.net/public/ue339b1/)!

Comment: NO - the modify SQL XML DML is available in SQL Server 2005, too!

Comment: You need to be EXTREMELY careful with your casing, though! The method is called "modify" (all lower-case) - *NOT* "Modify".

Comment: Ahh!  Red-Gate SQL Prompt is automatically upper-casing it.  :-D  SHIGGITY! :-D

Comment: <hehe> I have strongly complained with Red-Gate about that behaviour for a long time - without much luck so far :-( Just turn off SQLPrompt for now, or manually lowercase it all again.

Comment: I'm getting so close, but still battling errors.  The latest still has to do with trying to dynamically set the XML inside the insert statement.  Any particular approach you can advise?

Comment: ...here's my current error, just in case you're wondering: "Incorrect use of the xml data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context."  it's when I try to do ".modify(insert {sql:variable("@XMLVar")}...."

Comment: @STW fyi, your link is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
update yourTable
set (your XML column).modify('insert <processingData id="guid" someAttrib="x" /> as last into /someData[1]')
where .......
```

That should do it.

For more details on how to deal with XML in SQL Server 2005 and up, I keep going back to [this article at 15 seconds](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050803.htm) which shows really nicely how to insert, modify, and delete XML fragments inside your SQL server fields, using XML DML statements.

Marc

Comment: Great link :-) but unfortunately it looks like the Modify() function isn't supported by SQL Server 2005

Comment: Sure it is supported in SQL Server 2005! I use it almost every day.... what makes you say that??

Comment: Link is dead.  (I just end up at CodeGuru.com)